# lookup in Ext.StoreManager.lookup is not defined

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

This is my view:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Login.LoginForm',{
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'loginForm',
    requires: ['Ext.form.FieldSet', 'Ext.Img'],
    config: {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name: 'username',
                        required: true
                    },{
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name: 'password',
                        required: true,
                        inputType: 'password'
                    },{
                        xtype: 'selectfield',
                       //*****************the problem is here****************
                        store: Ext.StoreManager.lookup('MyApp.store.Tables')
                        //store: Ext.StoreManager.lookup('Tables')
                    }
                ]
            },{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Login',
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

It says that it cannot use `lookup of undefined`, so I'm thinking that MyApp doesn't see Ext.StoreManager.

I've also tried `Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup` and `Ext.StoreMgr`.
BTW. the store really exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your store config should be like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Tables', {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    config: {
        model: "MyApp.model.Table",
        data : [{
            text: "Ed",    
            value: "Spencer"
        }, {
            text: "Tommy", 
            value: "Maintz"
        }]
    }
});
```

And place this into your LoginForm.js:

```
{
      xtype: 'selectfield',
      store: 'Tables'
}
```

I have tested. It is working fine.

Comment: It works! Thank you! One more question, is this change just in Sencha Touch 2 or in ExtJS 4 newer versions as well? In earlier versions of ExtJS 4 I would do lookup for the store.

Answer (score 2):

Try following these instructions and let me know if it works:

1. Make sure to include the store in your `app.js` file
2. In `Tables.js` store implementation file, give it an `storeId` inside its config, like this: `config: {storeId: 'Tables'}`
3. Using this instead of Ext.StoreManager: `store: 'Tables'`

Hope it helps.

Comment: The answer before is the same but with a little more explanation. You will at least get +1 for me and a big thank you! :) (as soon as I get 15 points for upvoting) One more thing, why does it work without storeId?

Comment: Lol that's ok bro, sorry for my brevity :) About your question regarding storeId, yes it still works in this situation because behind the command `store: 'Tables'`, Sencha Touch looks for corresponding classname, which is `yourApp.store.Tables`. But it won't if sometimes you want to get the store instance directly through this `Ext.getStore('Tables')`

Comment: `Ext.getStore` is shorthand for `Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup`, which you tried to use before, that's why I mentioned `storeId` ;)

Comment: @Thiem: I want to correct you sir. Your last line is wrong. `Ext.getStore('Tables')` will work without the `storeId` also.

Comment: @AnandGupta: It might work but only in this case: you define the store without a storeId, then you use `Ext.getStore()` and pass the **designated id** of the store which is created by the framework itself, in this case, "Tables". If you change the storeId to smt else, let's say "store.Tables", Ext.getStore("Tables") will return `undefined`

Comment: and in all cases, do not rely on the existence of such default id created by the framework. It's always a better practice to explicitly declare your important configs instead, right?